# 'TypeError: 'DotMap' object is not callable' error at django model class

Tags: python, django

Has to be something obvious, but I can't figure it out.
I am trying to define class field of type [DotMap](https://github.com/drgrib/dotmap) in django's model class:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):

temp = { 'key': 'value' }

dot_map = DotMap(temp)
```

But I keep getting 'TypeError: 'DotMap' object is not callable' from 'python manage.py runserver'. I have `from dotmap import DotMap` at the start of the file. Would appreciate any ideas on what might cause it or how to fix it?

Stack trace:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by  
<function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x106a871e0>  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File ".../django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper  
fn(*args, **kwargs)  
File ".../django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run  
autoreload.raise_last_exception()  
File ".../django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception  
six.reraise(*_exception)  
File ".../django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise  
raise value.with_traceback(tb)  
File ".../django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper  
fn(*args, **kwargs)  
File ".../django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup  
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)  
File ".../django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate  
app_config.import_models(all_models)  
File ".../django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models  
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)  
File ".../python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module  
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed  
File ".../models.py", line 100, in <module>  
class Trade(models.Model):  
File ".../django/db/models/base.py", line 157, in __new__  
new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)  
File ".../django/db/models/base.py", line 316, in add_to_class  
value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)  
TypeError: 'DotMap' object is not callable
```

Comment: You have defined a `Dotmap Type Object` variable `dot_map`, but how did you use this variable, can you show me more code?

Comment: it fails upon loading SomeModel class, I don't even need any usage to fail it.

Comment: added stacktrace

Comment: Try defining dot_map variable outside Model class!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not initial DotMap type variable inside Django Model class, define it outside.

```
    temp = { 'key': 'value' }
    dot_map = DotMap(temp) 

    class SomeModel(models.Model):
        # use dot_map as you want 
        pass
```

Comment: Yeah, I understand it will work. My questions is why it fails? I guess django lose DotMap import at some point, but how and why it happens?

Comment: Django model is a subclass of `ModelBase`,  if it is  ModelBase type, each attribute which has `contribute_to_class` attribute, (you can find code in django.db.model.base.py in line 316),Django will call it's `contribute_to_class` to initial it .By chance, Dotmap type object has this attribute, so , your code will run this way :  `dot_map.contribute_to_class(ModelBase,"dot_map").